# ERROR Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs

I've built an about page for my react application. Unfortunately when I try to run it it seems that there is an error. [image: I get 5 of these]

I know this question gets asked often so I did search for an answer but I can't seem to have anything I find work correctly.

This is the code in my About .jsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import imgBannerAbout from "../../assets/banner-montagnes.png";
import Banner from '../../components/banner/Banner';
import './about.scss';
import Collapse from "../../components/collapse/Collapse";
import collapseData from '../../components/collapse/Collapse.json';

export function AboutPage() {
  return (
    <div className="about">
      <Banner image={imgBannerAbout} imageClassName="about-banner-image" banner="about-banner" imageAlt="paysage montagne" />
      <section className='container-collapses'>
        {collapseData.map((data) => (
          <Collapse key={data.id} id={data.id} title={data.title} content={data.description} />
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import {HomePage} from './pages/home/home';
import {AboutPage} from './pages/about/About';
import {LogementPage} from "./pages/logement/logement";
import {PageNotFound} from "./pages/notFound/pageNotFound";
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import {NavBar} from './components/navbar/navBar';
import './components/navbar/navbar.scss';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>             
            <NavBar />
              <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<HomePage/>}/>
                <Route path='/about' element={<AboutPage/>}/>
                <Route path='/logement' element={<LogementPage/>}/>
                <Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound/>}/>
              </Routes>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

This is the Banner component imported in AboutPage

```
    import '../../components/banner/banner.scss'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


function Banner(props) {
    return (
      <section className="banner">
        <div className={props.banner}>
          <img className={props.imageClassName} src={props.image} alt={props.imageAlt} />
          <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
  

  Banner.propTypes = {
    imageClassName: PropTypes.string,
    image: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    imageAlt: PropTypes.string,
    banner: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
}

  export default Banner;
```

And this is the collapse component

```
import './collapse.scss'
import { useState } from "react"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Arrow from "src/assets/Vector.png"

const Collapse = ({ title, content }) => { //Cette ligne définit une fonction fléchée (arrow function) appelée Collapse qui prend deux propriétés (title et description) en tant que paramètres. Ce composant sera utilisé pour afficher un collapse avec un titre et une description.
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false); //Cette ligne utilise le hook useState de React pour créer une variable d'état isOpen et une fonction setIsOpen pour la mettre à jour. L'état initial de isOpen est défini sur false, ce qui signifie que le collapse est initialement fermé.
  
    const toggleCollapse = () => { //Cette ligne définit une fonction toggleCollapse qui est appelée lorsque l'utilisateur clique sur le titre du collapse. Elle inverse la valeur de isOpen en utilisant la fonction setIsOpen, c'est-à-dire qu'elle ouvre le collapse s'il est fermé et le ferme s'il est ouvert.
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="collapse">
        <div className='titreCollapse' onClick={toggleCollapse}>
            <h2>{title}</h2> 
            <img className={`arrow ${isOpen ? 'arrow--open' : ''}`} src={Arrow} alt=""></img> 
        </div>
        
        <ul className={isOpen ? 'descriptionCollapse' : 'descriptionCollapse_hidden'}>
          {Array.isArray(content) ? content.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>{item}</li>
            )
          }) : content
        }
        </ul>
        
      </div>
    );
    // Lorsque l'utilisateur clique sur l'en-tête title, la fonction toggleCollapse est appelée.
    // la description est affichée seulement si isOpen est true, c'est-à-dire que le collapse est ouvert. Lorsque isOpen est false, le contenu du collapse est masqué.
  };
  
  export default Collapse;

Collapse.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    content: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}
```

[image: This is how my files are arranged]

I tried exporting as a defult function and deleting the brackets in my app.js file, since it seems to be a problem that happens frequently but it hasn't changed anything.

Since I am using a named export andusing a named import so I don't see where  the problems is.

Comment: Check the components imported in the `AboutPage` component are correct.